# CakePhp 3 use of Foundation icons in grid

Tags: php, zurb-foundation, frontend, cakephp-3.0

I want to use Foundation icons into the grid of index in a view replacing the words "view", "edit" and "delete", I have tried many combinations and search but I can't find how to do it.
It is necessary hard code the grid or is possible such a replace?

Comment: Your code sample could help us understand better.

Comment: It is simple, the generated code goes this way:                                       **<?= $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), ['action' => 'edit', $brand->id]) ?>
<?= $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), ['action' => 'delete', $brand->id], ['confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', $brand->id)]) ?>**     I want add **<i class="fi-eye"></i>** and replace the label but I can't find how to do that